# Facebook: posting a fitness.bikes OpenGraph action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to submit a fitness.bikes story from a Windows Phone app. Ideally I'd like it to look the same way it does in the documentation -- a table of stats, and a course map. I'm trying to figure out how to make that happen. Specifically, whether it's possible to make it happen without a 3rd party server hosting the ride data.

Questions:

1. When I am submitting a course object to Facebook, can I specify all needed ActivityDataPoints to make the map show up, or is something else needed?
2. In the sample post I've been trying, all I get is the Title, the Image, and the Description. Can I get the table of stats to show up, without needing an external server?
3. The posts I'm sending are not appearing on the Timeline, even for a test user. They do appear in the Activity Log, and are marked with "Allowed on Timeline", not "Showing on Timeline." I'm using fb:explicitly_shared... shouldn't the post show up?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after further experimentation, I believe I can answer my own questions:

1. The fitness.bike activity post data should contain only fb:explicitly_shared, privacy, and course links, and nothing else. For some reason adding created_time makes the post appear in standard layout.
2. Same answer as above. Table of stats is part of the Map layout Facebook provides.
3. Same answer as above. Removing the created_time attribute magically makes the post appear correctly on the timeline.

P.S. As far as an external server -- it is necessary only if you want to redirect the user to your own page. Even then, the server can grab the object_id from the URL, grab an access token from Facebook using AppID and AppSecret, then lookup that object (course), extract data out of it, and show on the page.

Hope this helps someone else.